# Which Agatha Christie book was this adaption with an Irish woman committing suicide based on?

Tags: identification-request, agatha-christie, hercule-poirot

When I was a young boy I viewed one filmed book from Agatha Christie on television with David Suchet. Now I would love to read that book but I forgot its name. I remember only few facts.

I remember the end of the film. There was a woman, an Irish woman. She and her followers were somewhere in the countryside in a castle. There was a politician of the British parliament as a prisoner. This group of people fought against Britain in many ways. At the end of this film the Irish woman stood on the roof of the castle and she said words such *"erin cobra"* (I remember it sounded something like that), then she put a pistol to her head and committed suicide and her body fell on the ground. The British politician was alive.

Which book was this episode based on?

Comment: Here's a list of episodes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Agatha_Christie%27s_Poirot_episodes : unfortunately you'll need to click each one to see the plot !

Comment: Not all those episodes were based on books, particularly in the later series.  You may not find a book.

Comment: The “erin cobra” you heard is probably [Erin go Bragh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erin_go_bragh). And that leads to *The Kidnapped Prime Minister* as the one you saw. This is based on the short story of the same name, from the book (short story collection) [*Poirot Investigates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Poirot_Investigates&oldid=800949071#The_Kidnapped_Prime_Minister). (I don't have time to write a proper answer now, so apologies for answering in the comments.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, you are right. It was the episode. Thank you.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Are you going to write an answer for this? I also knew the answer but you were here first so if you would prefer to...

Comment: @mirte no I'm not going to. Please post an answer

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič Please consider accepting the answer below from Mirte (by clicking the ✓ on the left), since you've confirmed it as correct in comments.

Answer (score 2):

As ShreevatsaR said:

The phrase you heard is [Erin go Bragh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erin_go_bragh), said by Irish Freedom sympathisers who kidnapped the Prime Minister.

The [short story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poirot_Investigates#The_Kidnapped_Prime_Minister) and the [episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0676177/) both go by the name: The Kidnapped Prime Minister. The short story is in the book [Poirot Investigates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poirot_Investigates).